# Is "use" as a verb being used properly in this summary sentence?

Tags: word-usage

The suggested summary sentence :

> The judge decided who the real owner of the horse was using the horse.

The background story goes as in the following:

*Judge*: (asking the man) Why did you repay this man’s kindness with your bad ways? Good traveler, the horse is yours.

*King*: Tell me, how did you know that I was the owner of the horse?

*Judge*: I had your horse put in a stable next to the court. When the man passed by, the horse never looked up. When you passed, he made a loud sound. It is your horse.

*King*: (surprised) You are a wise judge! I am the king. I'll make you the High Court Judge in the capital city!

The definition of 'use' is to do something with ~'. In the above passage, it doesn't seem that the judge did something with the horse. To me, "using" in the following summary doesn't seem right. Instead, I think "watching/observing/looking at" sounds more right. What do you think?

Comment: Yes; in that sense, you are casting the horse as an instrument. A tool. Perfectly fine. But consider that approach de-animates the horse a bit, removes its life and autonomy (remember it was the *horse* who chose to whinny at the King's passing, unprompted by the judge or anyone else). So instead you might say: "The king determined the real owner of the horse *by its reaction*". See also our sister site, [ELL.se].

Comment: All three dictionaries at _The Free Dictionary.com_ give as the most common sense of _use_ a variant of 'v.tr.
1. To put into service or employ for a purpose: _I used a whisk to beat the eggs. The song uses only three chords._ {[AHDEL](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/use)}. /  To avoid a garden-path sentence, a comma before, or parentheses around 'using the horse' are required.

Comment: ... [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/use_1) has: _use_ 1 [TRANSITIVE] to do something using a machine, tool, skill, method etc in order to do a job or to achieve a result
... 
Using all his charm, he managed to persuade them.

Answer (score 2):

It's grammatically and semantically correct, although it's difficult to interpret in the latter sense, if not outright ambiguous. I'd advise including the word a preposition such as "by" (as mentioned by TechnoGeezer), i.e.:

> The judge decided who the real owner of the horse was ***by*** using the horse.

Of course, your alternatives (I particularly like "observing") would also work (and are perhaps more suited to the situation than the more-general "using"), although they'd also likely benefit from the use of a preposition.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing grammatically incorrect about the use of "using" in that sentence, but the syntax -- or, more precisely, the repetitions in "the horse was using the horse" -- makes the last half of the sentence terribly confusing. Have a look at the following suggestion as a way to phrase the idea; it is a phrasing which still retains the word "using," but is considerably clearer than the original:

The judge decided who the real owner of the horse was by using the horse.

Comment: Or maybe "The judge used the horse to determine its real owner."

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the verb "used" is used properly, appropriately, and with 100% grammatical correctness, in the sentence suggested by Sven Yargs: "The judge used the horse to determine its real owner." Sven's suggestion that *decided*, in the original sentence, be changed to *determine*, alters some of the meaning, but only very slightly, and in a clever and effective way. The suggested change obviates the whole "who" clause in the original; but the new version still clearly implies that there *is* a "who" involved, by way of the "its real owner" phrase at the end.   **Superb rewrite, Sven!**